# PHP Validation style Error

Tags: php

I've made this form with a php validation, Then tried to make a red border around the input in case something is wrong in the input after submitting, But when i click on submit, All the inputs disappears except Username and the style doesn't work, Is there something wrong with the formation of the code?

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];

          if(!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{4,}$/", $username) || empty($username)) {$uErr = "style='border: 2px solid red";}

            elseif(!preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})$/", $password) || empty($password)) {$pErr = "style='border: 2px solid red";} else {
            echo "Executed";}} ?>


    <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input <?php if(isset($uErr)){echo $uErr;} ?> name="username" type="text" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password:</label>
            <input <?php if(isset($pErr)){echo $pErr;} ?> name="password" type="password" class="form-control">
            <button name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: You assign a style to `$uErr` when an error occurs. You use a quote in these styles before `border` which should not be there. Try this: `$uErr = 'style="border: 2px solid red"';`

Comment: You also had a missing semicolon in your style { $uErr = 'style="border: 2px solid red; " ' ; }

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Oh, that solved it, But why does it work in order? it doesn't border all inputs at the same time.

Comment: @Calibur: I would expect it to border all inputs at the same time, regardless of which error was detected.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Just tried it, If i didn't type in both UN and PW only UN gets the border, If i typed in the UN, Only PW gets the border in case there is a 3rd input after PW.

Comment: @Calibur: Ah, yes, I take back my previous comment: `$uErr` is clearly not the same as `$pErr`... I didn't spot the difference in one letter. Why not call them `$usernameError` and `$passwordError`? You have to pay someone by the keystroke? ;-) Anyway; you are using the structure `if () elseif ()` hence the bordering you see. Perhaps you intended `if ()` and `if ()` ?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware is there a better way to validate than mine? That would border all the invalid fields, If i used if() and if() i don't know how to execute the last code if they're vaild. The code executes anyway if i used if if  only

Comment: See my answer, that doesn't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're just not ending the quotes in your style tags.
When defining $uErr and $pErr you're missing one ' .
Define $uErr with 
`$uErr = "style='border: 2px solid red'";`
and $pErr with
`$pErr = "style='border: 2px solid red'";`
Notice I added the ' before the final "

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean flag variable, like this:

```
<?php 

  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $hasError = FALSE;
    if (!preg_match("/^[0-9a-zA-Z_]{4,}$/",$username) || empty($username) {
      $usernameStyle = 'style="border: 2px solid red"';
      $hasError      = TRUE;
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^.*(?=.{8,})$/",$password) || empty($password)) {
      $passwordStyle = 'style="border: 2px solid red"';
      $hasError      = TRUE;
    } 
    if (!$hasError) {
      echo "Executed";
    }
  } 

?>
```

Comment: Oh, We use another variable to sign it, Wouldn't it be better if we removed $hasError and just used '!$hasError = TRUE' But yet, it still works, Thank you.

Comment: Anything is possible. You could also use the opposite: `$noError = TRUE;` and then when there's is an error: `$noError = FALSE;` or any variation you like. The point is: It is possible.